# Evaluate $\int (x^2-6)^3 (2x)\,dx$ using $u$ substitution

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

Section 5.2

Can somebody verify my solution? Thanks

---

Evaluate $\int (x^2-6)^3 (2x)dx$ using $u$ substitution

Let $u = x^2-6$. Then $\frac{du}{dx} = 2x$

and so, by multiplying both sides of the equation by $dx$ and then dividing by $2x$:

$\frac{du}{2x} = dx$

$\rightarrow \int (x^2-6)^3(2x)dx = \int u^3 2x \frac{du}{2x} = \int u^3 du$

And finally,

$\int u^3du = \frac{u^4}{4} + C = \frac{(x^2-6)^4}{4}+C$

Comment: It's correct. You would make it a bit siorter using differentials: from $u=u^2-6$, you deduce instantly that $\mathrm du=2x\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: @amWhy: Sorry for the typo, I've seen your comment a bit late, so I'll write an errata comment: from $u=x^2−6,$  one deduces instantly that $\mathrm du=2x\,\mathrm dx$.

Comment: No problem, @Bernard

Comment: @MSV  After having asked four very rudimentary u-sub questions in one hour, I am inclined to vote to close as duplicates of your current questions any such rudimentary u-sub question you ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct. A very useful thing you can do with indefinite integrals is to derive (when possible if the calculations aren't too much) the result, if it gives you the integrand function then your result is correct for sure.
Indeed
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left[\frac{(x^2-6)^4}{4}+C\right]=4\frac{(x^2-6)^3}{4}(2x)=(x^2-6)^3(2x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is correct (and revert the substitution in the end!). Please consider using an online-calculator (like [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+%28x%5E2-6%29%5E3%282x%29) or [SymbolLab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/integral-calculator/%5Cint%20%5Cleft(x%5E%7B2%7D-6%5Cright)%5E%7B3%20%7D%5Cleft(2x%5Cright)dx)) for verifying your solutions instead of asking multiple question of the same kind within a short period of time (see [a relevant post here on MSE.Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3472/how-much-asking-is-too-much?noredirect=1&lq=1)).

Note that SymbolLab offers a step-by-step solution aswell.

Comment: Indeed, @MSV, take advantage of either link.  In case you are unaware of rate limits for asking questions, there are such rate limits, per week, and per month.  So if you can verify a solution on either of the tow links mrtaurho provides, you then can use your allotment of questions for problems on which you are stuck.